# What it means to "Avoid handling errors by catching non-specific exceptions"?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm new to C#,
I'm currently learning about exceptions & exception handling when came across this statement:

> Avoid handling errors by catching non-specific exceptions, such as System.Exception, System.SystemException, and so on, in application code. There are cases when handling errors in applications is acceptable, but such cases are rare.

I just don't get it. Would you please explain what does it mean?
I was thinking handling all exceptions would be a good practice because it makes the program more stable in unpredicted situations.

[MSDN Exception and Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229005(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Exception` is the base class that all exceptions in .NET inherit from. What the author ment is that usually, when you use `catch (Exception e)`, you're doing a general catch-all-exceptions kind of catch, instead of handling the actual specific exceptions. For example, if you do an HTTP request from a method that may throw a `WebException`, then catching a `WebException` and handling that error is what you should do.

The author means, that usually when you catch specific exceptions, you actually want to be handling the error which came from that request. This can mean, for example, catching a `WebException` and implementing a retry mechanism when you're dealing with a faulty network connection.

This means to do:

```
public void DoRequest()
{
    try
    {
        var address = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\text.txt");
        var client = new WebClient();
        var result = client.DownloadString(address);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        // Handle the specific case
    }
    catch (IOException ie)
    {
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
public void DoRequest()
{
    try
    {
        var address = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\text.txt");
        var client = new WebClient();
        var result = client.DownloadString(address);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Never understood it this much before.